# Devextreme dx-datagrid angular2, cascading dropdowns with unique values

Tags: json, angular, html.dropdownlistfor, devextreme

Hei,

I am trying to build Cascading dropdowns using DevExtreme controls inside the DevExtreme data grid. The problems I am facing are

1. There are non-unique values shown in the dropdown list. Can you help me to show only unique values in the dropdown list inside the ordreIDNummer column?
2. The 2 dropdowns are cascading, which means that based on the dropdown in jobbnavn field, the dropdown in the ordreIDnummer has to be displayed. I am not sure how to achieve these. 
   Below is the code for the grid I am using and pictures of the data that is being displayed at my end currently.
  {{cellData.value}}
  {{cellData.value | lowercase}}
        
        
        
        
        
               alignment="right">

[image]
[image]